# BlocksKit framework compiler error

Tags: ios, frameworks

I've try to build framework, but It returns a compiler error. How to solve this error?

[image]

Comment: Errors not viewable.can you post the error clearly?

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `W' in: -Wl,-no_compact_unwind
Command … failed with exit code 1

Comment: I've gotten this error too. removing the flags causes other errors to happen :(

Answer (score 1):

Blockskit depends on libffi which includes this flag in its podspec. However, it seems that it's no longer supported by the linker since version ld64-134.9 (you can check which version you're running by entering ld -v from the command line).

I've sent a pull request to correct this. In the meantime, the only solution I've found is to manually remove "-Wl,-no_compact_unwind" from the generated Pods.xconfig file after each time that I run "pod install". Btw, the problem occurs regardless of whether you're linking against a static library or an application.

I hope my fix will be merged soon.

**** Update ****

Fixed!

**** Update ****

Unfortunately the BlocksKit developer didn't accept my solution and the problem doesn't reproduce on his test machines. So the best option for now is:
1. Manually remove the flag after each "pod update" (as I mentioned above)
2. Fork BlocksKit, remove the compiler flag from there and then update your Podfile to point to your fork instead of the original project. You'll have to manually pull the original project now and then to stay up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking blockskit with a static library? i think the "-Wl,-no_compact_unwind" linker flag doesn't work there. A workaround could be to remove that flag from the xcconfig file generated by cocoapods perhaps? When I do that the error seems to disappear.